# How I put the getDuration in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to put the time duration of my datasource in a `TextView`

My code is

```
mp.setDataSource(URL);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
             int pos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
     int Durancion =  mp.getDuration();
          String.format("%d min, %d sec",
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Durancion),
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Durancion) -                     TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Durancion)));
     Tiempo.setText(Durancion);
```

Comment: `String.format();` returns the formatted `String`, so i guess you can do `Tiempo.setText(String.format(..<continue with the code>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the outcome of the `String.format()`, you can either simply put that whole method into the `setText` method or you could assign it to a variable and insert that into the `setText` method.